# PHP cURL can not keep session alive in remote site from live server

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl, remote-server

My site is www.xyz.com. From my site I want to login in a remote site(for example: www.newxyz.com/index.php). And then I want to get data from another page (for example: www.newxyz.com/viewInfo.php). For this I use cURL. Here is my code sample--

```
$loginUrl = 'www.newxyz.com/index.php';
$cookieFile = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."cookie.txt";
file_put_contents($cookieFile, "");
$post_data = 'username=myuser&password=mypass&action=login';
$ch = curl_init();
$agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 0);
curl_exec($ch);

$url = 'www.newxyz.com/viewInfo.php';
$postData = 'action=view';  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);

session_write_close();
$viewData = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($viewData);
```

This code is working well in my windows-7 local xampp server (version xampp-win32-1.8.1).
For example from local server it shows a user image link which is the logged in user's image. But when I upload this code in my live server it shows **wrong data**. From the live server it shows that image link as a default link which is not the logged in user's image. My live server is a linux server which php version is 5.2.8. I need help.

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553130/why-do-i-get-wrong-data-using-curl

Comment: This code do not produce error. But shows some data which is not related to logged in information.

Comment: You should clarify that in your question, because I had no idea what you were talking about.

Comment: P.S. PHP 5.2? It's definitely time to upgrade that thing.